# Вставить переменную в класс VUE.js

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.7

Изучаю Vue.js с Laravel. В Laravel в шаблонах blade я могу вставлять переменные в классы. Пример:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-outline-{{$datalist->makeup->tag}} btn-sm" ></a>
```

Т.к. адаптирую шаблон под vue, стоит задача сделать тоже самое. Я делаю:

```
<div v-for="datalist in datalists" v-bind:key="datalist.id">
    <!-- Не работает класс -->
    <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-{{datalist.makeup.tag}} btn-sm" >{{datalist.name}}</a>
</div>
```

И синтаксис неправильный. Как можно встроить переменные в класс vue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй через [бинд](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html):

```
<div v-bind:class="'btn btn-outline-'+datalist.makeup.tag+' btn-sm'"></div>
```